# Google Geocoding API only works for one word address

Tags: php, geocoding, file-get-contents, google-geocoding-api

Google geocoding api is working fantastically if I use only one word like

> Sydney

But if I use:

> Sydney, Australia

It doesn't work it says:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sydney,
>   Australia&sensor=false): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>   HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Even though it works in my browser when I paste this url but when I use this function `file_get_contents` it doesn't.

My question is simple why it works in my browser when I paste this result and why it doesn't work with the code below. And of course how to fix this.

```
$a = file_get_contents("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sydney, Australia&sensor=false");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to url encode the address:

```
$a = file_get_contents("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . urlencode('sydney, Australia') . "&sensor=false");
```

Comment: `$address = urldecode($person_basic->address);`

`$a = file_get_contents("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $address . "&sensor=false");`

Still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Its the space what is causing problem here. People are using :

```
$address = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
```

PS. Its a late reply but may help some others who reach the page by searching, like me.